# Windows Office365 Outlook web addin not opening links in default browser

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

On our web-addin we have a side bar with an anchor link. This anchor link would open fine in the default browser on Mac Office 365 Outlook and Windows COM addin, however it opens in a dialog window on Windows Outlook 365 webaddin. Also F12 IEChooser developer tool is also not picking up the webaddin, debugging is not available as well.

link looks like this

The anchor link's domain is not in the whitelist of domain:

```
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://not_the_example_url.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://not.theexample2.com/</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
```

Versions affected:

- IE 11 ver 11.476.18.362.0
- Windows 10.0.18362 Build 18362
- Outlook MSO (16.0.12228.20202) 64Bit

Comment: Is the anchor link's domain the same as the source url domain of the addin?  That would also cause the link to open in dialog.  For debugging, have you looked at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10, especially for the steps on 'When the add-in is running in Microsoft Edge'

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The anchor link's domain is the same as the one in <SourceLocation /> of the manifest. Is there anyway we can get around that?

Comment: The behavior that you're seeing is by design. New windows are opened with Edge if it is the same domain in order to support using cookies to pass data to the window. If this is functionality you would like, please add a request to our UserVoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This behavior does not work for us. Is there a work around to get this to happen?